# Resource Stats is empty after upgrading to V12

Tags: azure-sql-database

We've just completed the upgrading of our SQL Azure from V11 to V12 a few hours ago, everything is running smoothly except that our sys.resource_stats are not returning any records at all. Viewing the monitoring in Azure portal, i'm getting the error that the server could not retrieve the metrics.

How do we fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have a defect in the service side and the fix is being rolled out soon. In the mean time please create a ticket against Microsoft and one of our engineers will fix it.